# android - Use text from EditText in activity1 on button in activity2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-button, android-bundle

I want the button in activity2 to show the text that was entered in EditText in activity1. This is my first app using more than one activity so  I may just be trying to pass things wrong. I've tried setting the button text to the direct EditText value by saving it but that didn't work right. Any direction would be much appreciated!

activity1

start_day is called when the button in activity1 is pressed. It sends the app into activity2.

```
public class AddTasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String taskOne = "Task One Content";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_tasks);
    }

    public void start_day(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DayTasksActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("taskOne", taskOne);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity2

Currently the button shows the text from activity1 "Task One Content." So I'm doing something right in passing things around but I can't seem to get anything but that working and I haven't quite found anything like this yet.

```
public class DayTasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_tasks);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String taskOne = bundle.getString("taskOne");

        Button buttonTaskOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_task_one);
        buttonTaskOne.setText(taskOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @rahul How to set the button to the value set in the edit text. Right now it doesn't do that. It just uses the String taskOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First give the id to your views in layout files
2. Then instantiate your views in respective Activity class
3. Then get he text from edit text and save it in bundle and pass it
4. get the value from the bundle in second activity
5. set the value in button

Activity1

```
public class AddTasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText myEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_tasks);
    myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.put_your_id_here_form_layout_file);
}

public void start_day(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DayTasksActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("taskOne", myEditText.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Activity2

```
public class AddTasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button buttonTaskOne;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_tasks);
    buttonTaskOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_task_one);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String taskOne = bundle.getString("taskOne");
    if (taskOne != null){
        buttonTaskOne.setText(taskOne);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the steps at the top. They definitely helped explain exactly what I'm doing rather than just copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

It is best that you use android studio. Because android studio takes care of the manifest file for you. and in eclipse you have to do the manifest part your self (defining the new activity in the manifest). @rahul made a good answer but i think that if it is just a string, it is better to use the putExtra and getExtra mehods and not using the bundle. here is a little bit different code:
first activity is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button btn;
public String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(!et.getText().toString().equals(""))

            str = et.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("key", str);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

}

second Activity is Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    str = Main2Activity.this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    btn.setText("" + str);
}
}
```

Comment: yes i know it uses a bundle. but it is less code, and implemented by google.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmm, well less code and less number of line are two different things. sometimes less number of line does not mean less code. And there is always a tradeoff b/w less line/code and robustness. we can apply null check also in bundle just to be sure and robust. its always good to share and learn.

Comment: yeah you are right. But my experience have proved to me, that using google codes, instead of implementing them by myself is way better. thank you.

Comment: I do use android studio. I had attempted to do .putExtra and .getExtra but it just never worked out for me. Probably just because I was doing something simple wrong. As is my app works well with rahul's answer so I'll probably just keep it but thank you for the different way of doing things. I'm sure it will be helpful when I do more complex apps.